# After saving in a form i want it to point to another site not the forms list

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

It's probably a stupid question.

I have a form on a custom list that I hade to custom design (the form for editing). But because of the law (GDPR) I can't let the users see the list after they save the form.
One part is sloved by them entering in the form from a page with a direct link to it. But the relinking is not.

This is the original part that I figured I have to change

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton2"/>
```

I changed It to this

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton  RedirectUrl="http://www.google.com" runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton2"/>
```

This also hellped but It just retuns me to the same empty form.

Can you tell me what I have to change to get it to actualy link it to the redirect link?

Comment: After some time i found the answer here:
[Solution](https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/How-to-Redirect-to-a-different-page-after-adding-new-list-items-in-SharePoint/) Actualy It's quite a normal problem if you have a source that navigates you back to your list you simply have to make the source be a diferent one than the list.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand your question, you want to redirect users to another site after they've submitted a form.

What I have done in the past is modify the URL of the new form so that instead of the new item url being : http://mysite/org/hr/Lists/Exit/Item/newifs.aspx?List=b5b9e317%2D4366%2D4557%2D8d29%2Db5dedc71a75a**&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite%2Forg%2Fhr%2FLists%2FExit%2FCompleted%2Easpx&RootFolder=&Web=a86f3198%2D79a6%2D4e7f%2Daa26%2D448559533df8**

I change the address after &Source in the above URL to the other site. So, it would now look like this:
http://mysite/org/hr/Lists/Exit/Item/newifs.aspx?List=b5b9e317%2D4366%2D4557%2D8d29%2Db5dedc71a75a**&Source=http://www.google.com**

What will happen, form will open, they'll save, and once the form closes, it will direct them to Google. I didn't need to modify the OOB save buttons - it's a good deal cleaner and quicker!

Hope this helps.